# how remove SQL where it can be compared with multiple columns

Tags: sql, mariadb

How can I delete data from a table in my database? For example, put a syntax where

```
delete from table_users where users or password or email or name = "perico"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a trick you can use with a tuple:

```sql
DELETE
FROM table_users
WHERE 'perico' IN (users, password, email, name);
```

Note: If you are actually storing plain text in your password column then you should *stop* and instead read about hashing and salting passwords.  Clear text passwords in a database are a huge security risk.